# Searching for a maximally nonlinear but smooth bijective mapping $[0,1]^N \mapsto [0,1]^N$

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus

**Question:** I am searching for a maximally nonlinear but still smooth (or at least differentiable) bijective (!) mapping $[0,1]^N \mapsto [0,1]^N$ between multivariate uniform spaces.

So far I've been toying around with convex linear combinations and invertible elementwise nonlinearities (e.g. cosine) but usually the mapping is not bijective (on the uniform space).

Comment: What is maximally nonlinear?

Comment: I am happy here with a subjective measure of "nonlinearity" as I want to use this in a small toy example for which the perceptual (thus subjective) strength of the nonlinearity is most important.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:[0,1]\mapsto [0,1]$ be the cantor function. Then, 
$$ g(x) = \frac{f(x) + x}{2} $$ 
is a bijective and continuous mapping from $[0,1]$ into itself. Obviously $$ G(x_1,\dotsc,x_N) = (g(x_1), \dotsc, g(x_N)) $$
is a bijective and continuous mapping from $[0,1]^N$ into itself.

$G$ is quite non-linear in the sense that it isn't even absolutely continuous. However, as $g$ is monotonous, it has bounded variation.

Comment: The cantor function is an interesting suggestion! Thanks! However, since it can only be applied to each entry individually there is no mixing between the different entries [x_1, ..., x_N], which at least limits the degree of "nonlinearity".

Comment: @user45893: If you want, just mix them. There is no precise definition of "maximally" nonlinear anyway.